# Executing VBA macro for Oracle Smartview

Tags: oracle, excel, vba

I have a Macro script written to get data using Oracle Smartview. When I execute the macro in sheet, the operation works flawlessly. When I try executing the same through a VB script, the execution fails:

```
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcel.Workbooks.Open "C:\Test.xlsm"
oExcel.visible = true
oExcel.Application.Run "MyMacro"
oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
Set oExcel = Nothing
```

What I noticed was the SV addin doesn't seem to load when I do this.

So while opening the sheet normally addin loads fine and executes the macro. Using script to evoke the macro doesn't seem to work.

Thanks to Rory's comment, I have now included the code for loading the addin. Issue is the HsTbar.xla doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExceL.Workbooks.Add
Set oAddin = oExcel.AddIns.Add("C:\Oracle\SmartView\bin\HsTbar.xla")
oAddin.Installed = False
oAddin.Installed = True
oExcel.Workbooks.Open "C:\Test.xlsm"
oExcel.visible = true
oExcel.Application.Run "MyMacro"
oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
Set oExcel = Nothing
```

The addin loads fine but is broken and still the macro doesn't execute.

Comment: You have to explicitly load the add-in in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but what you need to do is navigate to:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\SmartView\Bin

There is a file called "smartview.bas" there that you need to add as a module in your PERSONAL.XLSB VBAProject.

For information on creating the PERSONAL.XLSB file:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-save-all-your-macros-in-a-single-workbook-66c97ab3-11c2-44db-b021-ae005a9bc790